# Why should I catch bugs?

Tags: yo-kai-watch

Now, I am playing the demo version of Yo-Kai Watch, so maybe the full version answers this.

You can catch bugs on various trees and stuff, in the game. What good is catching bugs? Are they just a collectible, or do they serve a purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/yo-kai-watch/Catching_Bugs):

> Catching Bugs is one of the side options available in Yo-kai Watch. Bugs can be sold or traded for useful items at the Jungle Hunter facility.

Answer (score 0):

You can exchange them for items at jungle hunter, catch a sawtooth stag for draggie later (if you dont have draggie yet) or just to impress your friends :3